# Find string in array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have a fun challenging problem. So I have a mutable array that contains all of my **items.** I have a textfield that **might have one or two of these items if the person types them in. **

```
items= [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"apple", @"orange", @"pear", nil];

items2= [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"cheese", @"milk", @"eggs", nil];

Allitems= [NSMutableArray array];
[Allitems addObjectsFromArray:items];
[Allitems addObjectsFromArray:items2];

NSArray*WORDS =[Textfield componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

**I am trying to detect what specific words from **Allitems** are in the textfield. (If the textfield contains any string from ALLitems, how can I find what specific string?**

```
for (int i = 0; i < [Allitems count]; i++)
{
      NSString *grabstring;
      grabstring=[Allitems objectAtIndex:i];

      if (textfield isEqualto:grabstring){
        ?????
           pull that specific string from allitems.


     }
}
```

Comment: You can use a `NSPredicate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the intersection of two sets:

```
NSMutableSet* intersectionSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:Allitems];
[intersectionSet intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:WORDS]];
NSArray* intersectionArray = [intersectionSet allObjects];
```

After this `intersectionArray` contains the items that are present in both `Allitems` and `WORDS`.

BTW, why do you capitalise variable names in a non-standard and inconsistent manner?  Why not just `allItems` and `words`?

As @Arkku suggests: It's better to switch the arrays. In your example it does not matter much, but in case `Allitems` were (very) big, you can save (a lot of) memory and CPU usage:

```
NSMutableSet* intersectionSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:WORDS];
[intersectionSet intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:Allitems]];
NSArray* intersectionArray = [intersectionSet allObjects];
```

Comment: The issue is that the intersection should be case sensitive. I know the user didn't speak about it, but we can imagine that may be an issue he/she didn't think about.

Comment: @Larme Good to bring up this point, which also crossed my mind. But it's not an issue at the moment.

Comment: @techman9 Well, this code gives you a list of words that appear in both arrays, and that's what you wanted.  I've added one more line that places the result back in an array.

Comment: @techman9 Please note that this answer you accepted has the sets the wrong way around; `intersectionSet` should be created with `WORDS`, not `Allitems`, because now every time you create a new set of the larger `Allitems` only to discard most (or all) of them immediately in `intersectSet`. Create a global set of all items and make `intersectionSet` from `WORDS` (see my answer). This may not seem important with your given (very small) set of items, but it's a very simple fix and would make a huge diference if `Allitems` was, say, millions of items. Best learn the correct pattern immediately.

Comment: @meaning-matters Please consider editing the answer to switch places of of the sets, so that the `NSMutableSet` is created out of `WORDS` instead of `Allitems`. (Consider if `Allitems` was a million items; then every time this matching was done you'd create insert all million of them into a new set, then lose all but 0-2 of them in `intersectSet`. Meanwhile if you create the `NSMutableSet` with `WORDS`, it is only 0-2 items inserted and possibly removed. It's a difference of some 2 million insertions/removals.)

Comment: @Arkku Very good point, thanks! I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @meaning-matters Thanks for the edit, although it still has the problem that `[NSSet setWithArray:Allitems]` creates a new set every time this intersection is done, so now it's still costing the insertions (but not the removals). There should be a persistent set created out of `Allitems` (or, preferably, `Allitems` should _be_ an `NSMutableSet` instead of `NSMutableArray`) - @techman9 take notice. =)

Answer (score 1):

There are a various ways of doing it, each with different pros and cons. Let's have the following (consistently capitalized) variables in common for each case:

```
NSArray *allItems = @[ @"apple", @"orange", @"pear", @"cheese", @"milk", @"egg" ];
NSString *textFieldText = @"CHEESE ham pear";
NSArray *words = [textFieldText.lowercaseString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

### NSPredicate

```
NSArray *matchingItems = [allItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                          [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", words]];
```

This is perhaps the shortest (in lines of code) way, but not the most performant if `allItems` can be very long as it requires traversing all of it.

### Iteration

Of course you could also simply iterate over the collection and do the matching manually:

```
NSMutableArray *matchingItems = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *item in allItems) {
    if ([words containsObject:item]) {
        [matchingItems addObject:item];
    }
}
```

Again requires traversing all of `allItems` (although you could `break` the iteration if all words are matched).

In addition to the `for` loop there are of course many other ways for iteration, e.g., `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`, but they are unlikely to have any advantage here.

### NSSet

`NSSet` is often a good option for this kind of matching since testing set membership is faster than with `NSArray`. However, if using the most straightforward method `intersetSet:` (in `NSMutableSet`) care must be taken to not inadvertently create a large mutable set only to discard most of its items.

If the order of `allItems` does not matter, the best way would be to change it from an array into a set and always keep that set around, i.e., instead of creating the array `allItems`, you would create an `NSSet`:

```
NSSet *setOfAllItems = [NSSet setWithArray:allItems];
```

Or if it needs to be mutable:

```
NSMutableSet *setOfAllItems = [NSMutableSet set];
[setOfAllItems addObjectsFromArray:items1];
[setOfAllItems addObjectsFromArray:items2];
```

Then, when you have that set, you create a temporary mutable set out of `words` (which is presumably always the smaller set):

```
NSMutableSet *setOfMatches = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:words];
[setOfMatches intersectSet:setOfAllItems];
NSArray *matchingItems = setOfMatches.allObjects;
```

This would be likely be the most performant solution if `setOfAllItems` is large, but note that the matches will then need to be exact. The other methods are more easily adapted to things like matching the strings in `words` against fields of objects or keys in a dictionary (and returning the matched objects rather than the strings). In such a case one possibility to consider would be an `NSDictionary` mapping the words to match to the objects to return (also fast to then iterate over `words` and test for membership in the dictionary).

### Conversion to string

And, since the question included conversion of matches to a string:

```
[matchingItems componentsJoinedByString:@", "]
```

In the example case this would result in the string `"pear, cheese"` (or possibly `"cheese, pear"` if using sets).